# Retrieve visualization metrics for Linkedin Stories

Tags: linkedin-api

I got surprised when `/ugcPosts` started to return LinkedIn's Stories and I couldn't find any doc explaining this new behavior.

So as I'm exposing these stories to my client I do need to retrieve some metrics like visualizations. Does anyone knows if it's possible?

I tried using `videoAnalytics` endpoint but as it's suggests it works only for videos, which is not the case. I also tried using `organizationalEntityShareStatistics` endpoint but it is insufficient because it doesn't return visualization value.

Comment: What do you mean by `visualization value`?

Comment: @RishiDua how many times the story has been viewed